# Linq to XML C# Adding parent to child nodes in datagridview

Tags: xml, linq, datagridview

Not sure if I'm even asking the question properly, but I am trying to get "Jim" to show in a datagrid for both of his jobs using the xml doc below.
My expected result:

```
Jim, male, mechanic,joe's shop
Jim, male, janitor, microsoft
```

XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employment>
    <Person>
        <Name>
            <![CDATA[Jim]]>
        </Name>
        <Gender>
            <![CDATA[male]]>
        </Gender>
        <Jobs>
            <Job>
                <Title>
                    <![CDATA[mechanic]]>
                </Title>
                <Company>
                    <![CDATA[joe's shop]]>
                </Company>
            </Job>
            <Job>
                <Title>
                    <![CDATA[janitor]]>
                </Title>
                <Company>
                    <![CDATA[microsoft]]>
                </Company>
            </Job>
        </Jobs>
    </Person>
</Employment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LINQ2XML fetching the data could be done like this (the variable xmlSource holds the xml code):

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlSource);
var jobs = xml.Descendants("Job").ToList();
var person = xml.Element("Person").Elements("Name").First().Value;
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", person, job.Element("Title").Value));
}
```

For the DataGridView: add new row for every Person and new Cell for every job title / company or create a simple datasource, fill it with the data and give it to the DataGridView object.

Create a data object class **Person**:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

Create a **List** of **Person**'s, fill it with the data from the XML and set it as a DataSource to the DataGridView:

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlSource);
var jobs = xml.Descendants("Job").ToList();
var person = xml.Element("Person").Elements("Name").First().Value;
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    persons.Add(new Person 
    {
        Name = person,
        Title = job.Element("Title").Value,
        Company = job.Element("Company").Value
    });
}

dataGridViewControl.DataSource = persons;
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to be where I am having the problem, properly creating a datasource to populate the gridview.

Comment: I have updated my answer with code for creating the [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) Person, filling it from the XML and setting a List of Persons as the DataGridView data source.